# How to make two paragraphs of a text wrap around an image from both sides?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

After spending a lot of time I finally managed to do this:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const fimg = document.querySelector('#first img')
  const fimgWidth = fimg.getBoundingClientRect().width

  const simg = document.querySelector('#second img')
  const simgWidth = simg.getBoundingClientRect().width

  fimg.style.left = `${fimgWidth/2}px`
  simg.style.right = `${simgWidth/2}px`
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  flex: none;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  shape-outside: url("https://openclipart.org/download/318603/hand-written-circle-04.svg");
  position: relative;
}

#first img {
  float: right;
}

#second img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p id="first">
<img src="https://openclipart.org/download/318603/hand-written-circle-04.svg">
<span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
</p>
<p id="second">
<img src="https://openclipart.org/download/318603/hand-written-circle-04.svg">
<span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
</p>
</div>
```

I think my intent is clear: I have two paragraphs of text stacked horizontally, I place an image between them, I want them to wrap around this image nicely.

Even though the above solution does what I want I still have strong doubts if it is the right solution:

- Isn't getting the width of the image via Javascript a sign that I must've missed some obvious CSS way of doing this?

  - I want to place here a randomly chosen image out of a pool of available images, so I don't want to hardcode the image's width
- I had to resort to superimposing two copies of this image on top of each other. Do I really need to have two images where I want just one?

  - This didn't happen here or at least, if it happened, it is not evident because the image I chose to show the problem is so simplistic that it doesn't matter. But isn't stacking the images on top of each other plus the computations I'm doing here a recipe for images being stacked on each other incorrectly (one image being moved by a pixel in either direction relative to the other image) due to rounding errors and [sub-pixel problems](https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)?

Is there a more right-handed way of doing this?

Comment: @j08691 well i'm using it here...

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Exclusions](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-exclusions/) would help here: it allows you to wrap text around any element. Unfortunately, this spec is still a working draft, and [no browsers support it yet](https://caniuse.com/css-exclusions).